# how can i animate object as it doesn't exit from screen

Tags: android

i want to animate an object like this:
now my question is : how can i measure (b) that animate my object(o) without exiting from screen?

Object o;
nextX = random.nextInt(b);

ObjectAnimator a1 ;

a1 = ObjectAnimator.oFFloat( o , "x" , nextX )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the screen height and width

```
 public static int getScreenHeight(Context ctx) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return metrics.heightPixels;
    }

    public static int getScreenWidth(Context ctx) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return metrics.widthPixels;
    }
```

And use like this

```
Random randX = random.nextInt(getScreenWidth(ctx));
Random randY = random.nextInt(getScreenheight(ctx));

ObjectAnimator moveX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(object, "x", randX );
ObjectAnimator moveY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(object, "y", randY );
```